# angular 2 filter object in array

Tags: angular, filter

i want access to one filed in item

```
msgs : [];

  canReply() {
          var res = this.msgs.filter(a => a.ReplyId === null);
            if (res[0].StatusType >= 3)
          return false;
      else
          return true;
  }
```

but show me 
Cannot read property 'StatusType' of undefined

Comment: what is model can you please describe in bit more detail

Comment: You should provide more info.
Are you sure that there's at least one message without replies? Why don't you do this check?

Comment: You are filtering something called `msgs` into a new list you call `res`. You then check against something named `model` and never use the `res` again. Are you maybe confusing variables?

Comment: sry my friend im fix it

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your model[0] is undefined. This could be because of the way you populate the model, may be through an asynchronous call, then your code to access the statusType should be in the call back method or after promise, use $q for that in angular. Check the dev tools to debug, if model has a length > 0 or not.

Comment: $q in angular , i think he is referring to angular not angular js ?

Comment: im sry my question is wrong and im fix it. 
this.msgs have property

Comment: I meant promise in angular and $q in angularJS

Comment: plz help me my friend